# MongoEngine Dynamic Document

Tags: mongoengine

I have a dynamicdocument model, and one of the fields I'm trying to set is called "index_this"

I'm trying to set this field using dot notation:

```
In [17]: mongo_object.index_this = False

In [18]: mongo_object.save()

In [19]: mongo_object.index_this
Out[19]: True
```

But as you can see, the save method doesn't to work.

How are you supposed to save a single attribute when saving the model with a dynamic document?

Answer (score 2):

Your update is actually correct, but after saving the document you need to reload it to get its current state.

```
mongo_object.reload()
```

You can also use the update function:

```
mongo_object.update(set__index_this = False)
```

Or you can combine the update with the query like this:

```
Document.objects(pk="someid").update(set__index_this = False)
```